# Film about a man who had a boil on his shoulder that turned into another head

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember being quite young, so I would have seen it on television in the early 90's. It was a film about a man who developed a condition (can't quite remember the circumstances that brought about the situation) where a second head would grow and replace his own out of his shoulder, it slowly started to take over his life. It was all very strange. That's all I can remember unfortunately, so not a lot to go on.

Comment: Did it start out like a boil that started talking?

Comment: That does infact sound familiar, I think that occurs in a scene where he looks into a bathroom mirror at something on his shoulder and it does infact say something to him. But I could also be forming that image incorrectly in my mind.

Comment: The title could be asking for *Army of Darkness*.

Comment: family guy had an episode where this happened.

Comment: @Mazura: that was my first thought too.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think it is "[How To Get Ahead In Advertising](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097531/)"

> Dennis Dimbleby Bagley is a brilliant young advertising executive who can't come up with a slogan to sell a revolutionary new pimple cream. His obsessive worrying affects not only his relationship with his wife, his friends and his boss, but also his own body - **graphically demonstrated when he grows a large stress-related boil on his shoulder. But when the boil grows eyes and a mouth and starts talking**, Bagley really begins to think he's lost his mind

[image]

There is a good summary [here](http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/17072/looking-back-at-how-to-get-ahead-in-advertising)

Though I'm not sure if it counts as sci-fi.

Comment: Excellent answer, apoligies if it seems to be not strictly sci-fi, my memory of it was from when I was about 4-5 so I couldn't quite place a genre, felt sci-fi(y) to me when I thought back about it =)

Comment: My English teacher once told me that the exploration of individual is a natural Sci-Fi subject. While I have never seen this film it sounds like it would fall into that category.

Comment: TBH, most horror/monster movies fall under the umbrella of this site anyway.

Comment: Argh, the movie title "How to Get Ahead in Advertising" is possibly the worst pun on words in film history. :-P

Answer (score 21):

This is [How to get ahead in advertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Get_Ahead_in_Advertising)

[image: Movie poster for how to get ahead in advertising]

Richard E Grant plays an advertising exec who becomes convinced that an ugly boil on his neck speaks to him.  Eventually the boil grows to be another head and

> His actual head shrinks, the boil taking over his body

Comment: Sorry. Spent too long writing my answer and didn't see yours pop up

Comment: Sorry I couldn't mark both as the Answer, I realise you got to the title first, but Jeremey got the information in there quickest. But thank you for helping me realise my repressed fear of this film was misplaced =P

Comment: No worries pal :)

Answer (score 1):

There was a movie that I saw in the eighties called "The Boil." My friend and I still laugh about it because it was so bad, but other movies may have copied the premise.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a movie of that name; http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=the+boil&s=all